# How to get actual pixel indices from MATLAB function ginput?

Tags: image, matlab

I am using the MATLAB function *ginput* to label my image data for further process. Here is my code:

```
file_name = "test.jpg";

% Read the image
img = imread(file_name);

% Get the image dimension
imgInfo = imfinfo(file_name);
width = imgInfo.Width;
height = imgInfo.Height;

% Using ginput function to label the image
figure(1);
imshow(img);
hold on;
[x, y] = ginput(4); % Manually label 4 points
scatter(x, y, 100, 'ro', 'filled'); % Plot the marked points on img
hold off;
```

**My Problem:**

I found that the output `x` and `y`are not integers, so they are not representing the pixel indices.

Sometimes, these two conditions `max(x) > width` and `max(y) > height` are satisfied. It seems to suggest that the 4 points I marked using `ginput` are outside the image (but actually it is not).

I am aware of this issue is related to Image Coordinate System setting, but I am still not sure how to convert `x` and `y` obtained from `ginput` function to the actual pixel indices?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows a 2x2 image, enlarges the axes so we can see it, then turns on the axes ticks and labels. What this does is allow you to see the coordinate system used to render images in an axes object.

```
imshow([255,0;0,255])
set(gca,'position',[0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6])
axis on
```

[image]

The coordinates returned by `ginput` match these coordinates.

In short, what you need to do is simply round the coordinates returned by `ginput` to get indices into the image:

```
[x, y] = ginput(4); % Manually label 4 points
x = round(x);
y = round(y);
```